# how to deploy Angular 2 App to Github Pages?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, github

I was able to publish an app made with Angular Cli tool to Github Pages a few weeks ago, but now when I try to use the command `ng github-pages: deploy` I get the error: `The specified command github-pages:deploy is invalid.`. This [github thread](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/4385) suggests that the command has been removed recently, and petersgiles recommended following these guidelines instead to publish pages:

```
1. npm install -g angular-cli-ghpages (doesn't work if its not global)
2.Then in your package.json
"scripts": { "deploy": "ng build -sm -ec -bh /repo name/ & ngh --silent=false",...
3.when you want to deploy npm run deploy
```

I followed these instructions, but got the error: `Failed at the mybiography@0.0.0 deploy script 'ng build -sm -ec -bh /aboutme/ & ngh --silent=false'.` My npm and node js are up-to-date, and the error suggests that the problem is inside my `package.json` file.

My terminal proceeds to render all five chunks of my program, but there's no link to follow to the website. Is there anything i can do to fix this? I completed my website, and just need somewhere to host it. I'm very lost as a beginner, so please point out any obvious mistakes or missing info.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "aboutme",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "ng build -sm -ec -bh /aboutme/ & ngh --silent=false",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just wanted to update this old post with an answer that worked for me on this SO post: [how to publish to github pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626572/how-to-publish-to-github-pages/43675051?noredirect=1#comment74546481_43675051)

There is a new angular cli command to push to gh-pages, the old one no longer works. So you have to [install the new command](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-ghpages), build the project, then execute the push command.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (for mac) (does not require any changes to package.json) :

1. `$ npm install -g angular-cli-ghpages`
2. Push your code to a github repo and then run this in terminal: `ng build --env=prod --base-href "https://yourgithubusername.github.io/yourprojectname/"` here
   'yourprojectname' is the name of your github repo, not your local
   repo.
3. If everything works fine, then run : `sudo angular-cli-ghpages` and enter password.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `ngh --silent=false` throws an error. The command for running angular-cli-pages with verbose output at the time of this answer is `ngh --no-silent`

If you want to update your deploy script, take a look at the angular-cli-pages [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-ghpages) for commands to build and deploy:

`> ng build --prod --base-href "https://USERNAME.github.io/REPOSITORY/"`
`> ngh --no-silent`

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the simple way **without any third party plugin** you can deploy angular project to GitHub pages.

STEP 1: Open `angular.json` of your angular repo.

STEP 2: change `dist/your-project-name` to `docs/`

STEP 3: `ng build --prod --base-href=https://username.github.io/respository-name/`

change username to your GitHub username & respositoryName to repository name of your project.

STEP 4: Commit docs folder to local repo and push to github.
        `git add .`
        `git commit -m "generated deployables"`
        `git push -u origin master`

STEP 5: Open Github repo and open settings

STEP 6: Select `master branch /docs folder` in github pages.

Congrats !!

[Here](https://innovthemes.com/how-to-deploy-angular-app-to-github-pages/) is VERIFIED **step by step detailed guide Article** on how to deploy angular project to github pages, if you want more detailed article.