# how to publish to github pages?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, github-pages

i am having trouble understanding some basic instructions on publishing to github pages. There is a new way to publish Angular projects made with Angular Cli; i am following directions from [this page](https://github.com/angular-buch/angular-cli-ghpages) on the new command, `angular-cli-ghpages`:

```
Execute angular-cli-ghpages in order to deploy the project with a build from dist folder.
Note: you have to create the dist folder in before (e.g. ng build --prod)

Usage:

ng build --prod --base-href "https://USERNAME.github.io/REPOSITORY/"
angular-cli-ghpages [OPTIONS]
```

I created a dist folder for my project, and then run the ng build code. The terminal shows all the chunks have rendered, but i cannot find a link to the github page. I look in my repository on github and it is as if nothing has happened. Is this because i need to cd into a specific folder to execute angular-cli-ghpages? Here is my [repo](https://github.com/st4rgut25/aboutme), I would appreciate very much any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was successfully able to push to github pages using command

```
angular-cli-ghpages --repo=https://github.com/parthghiya/testrepo.git --name=parthghiya --email=parth.ghiya@knowarth.com --no-silent
```

Repo Link : https://github.com/parthghiya/testrepo

I did `ng build --prod --base href .`

Steps i Did :

1. Generated My SSH & Added it.

https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

2. Executed the push command.

[image]

**Edit :**

To Add more than one folders

Create folder parallel to assets, i created 2 folders Parth & Ghiya. Then added following entry in **angular-cli.json**

```
"assets": [
        "assets","parth","ghiya",
        "favicon.ico",
        "manifest.json"
      ],
```

So the dist folder now contains 3 folders now assets, parth & ghiya.
Then executed the above push command as earlier.

Comment: I published to github pages, but only the index.html file shows up: https://github.com/st4rgut25/biopage . How are you able to push folders and subfolders into the repo with the angular-cli-ghpages command? Thanks, I appreciate your help so far.

Comment: @st4rgut : you are welcomed :) ,please check edit & let me know if it helps or not.

Comment: thank you, but im still having trouble pushing subdirectories after modifying angular-cli.json.  I tried adding the file `src` to assets. Please see my edit for details

Comment: @st4rgut : but those are your development folders. Only things which would be pushed are contents of the dist folder. GitHub pages dont require anything except contents of the dist folder.

Comment: so I should be able to host my page without pushing the `src` file to the repo?

Comment: @st4rgut : yes. all you need is the dist folder!!

Comment: hmm, all  im getting on my project page is a loading screen. Do you think this is a problem with the build or one of my files?

Comment: check developer tools for errors ..! u did ng build --base-href . ?

Comment: @st4rgut Glad to Help :) :)

Comment: I'm trying to add `assets` folder, but images won't show up because there's a dot before assets in the img url eg `https://st4rgut25.github.io/biopage9/.assets/images/coop.gif` do you know how to get rid of it? The dot is not in my code, thanks

Comment: got it to work by building the project without the assets folder, then adding the folder to the new repo in github. That got rid of the `.` before assets

Answer (score 2):

The option to deploy to github via the angular cli was removed.

[See this change](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/4385)

Comment: i believe you are referring to the `github-pages:deploy` command? from my understanding, `angular-cli-ghpages' has replaced the old command, which no longer works

Comment: my apologies.... you are right, i was referring to the old command built into the CLI that has since been removed

Answer (score 1):

Try this (for mac) :

1. `$ npm install -g angular-cli-ghpages`
2. Push your code to a github repo and then run this in terminal: `ng build --env=prod --base-href "https://yourgithubusername.github.io/yourprojectname/"` here
   'yourprojectname' is the name of your github repo, not your local
   repo.
3. If everything works fine, then run : `sudo angular-cli-ghpages` and enter password.